# Access the value set in new form from the old form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `main` form. On this there is a button. When I click this button a new form is shown as shown is following code:

```
private void buLogOptions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    logOptionsForm logForm = new logOptionsForm();
    logForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

In this `logForm` I have a 'nud' and a 'Done_button'. After I set the nud value, I press 'Done button'. This closes this `logForm` and I am back at the `main` form. What I want is to get the value of nud I have set in logForm in the main form

Comment: Why are you so impatient? 5 min is not that long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a public get-only property in your logOptionsForm

```
public int Nud { get; private set;}
```

then set the Nud property and in the event handler for the "Done" button you set this.DialogResult property of the form like so

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
```

so that when the form closes you could do this

```
private void buLogOptions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    logOptionsForm logForm = new logOptionsForm();
    logForm.ShowDialog();

    if (logForm.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        logForm.Nud //do whatever you want with Nud
    }
}
```

The Nud property is get-only to avoid setting it outside the logOptionForm instance.

Comment: Use the DialogResult returned by ShowDialog() instead of IsDoneClicked.

Comment: @HansPassant yea that would be ideal.. But i forgot how to set it..haha been long since i did windows forms app. i think you set it by this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes.. or was it something different?

Answer (score 0):

If 'nud' is public you could just access it:

```
private void buLogOptions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   logOptionsForm logForm = new logOptionsForm();
   logForm.ShowDialog();
   var resultNud = logForm.nud;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could make a Public variable ?

```
    //This is on LogForm
    public bool pressed;


    //This is on your main from
    bool wasPressed = LogForm.pressed
```

It doesn't have to be strings though It'll work for any variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Main form Constructor that accept the parameter.

public MainForm(string Value) {

}

when your are click on Done button at that time

pass value to MainForm Object.

you can get that value in MainForm Constructor.